# Как добавить TextInput в AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть TextInput, находящийся в activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textField"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/enter_hint_name">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/findWordText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

который надо добавить в AlertDialog, код которого:

```
@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
public void SelectClick(View view) {
    if (hasPermissions()) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder alertDialog = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Введите значение для поиска");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_search_24);
        alertDialog.setBackground(this.getDrawable(R.drawable.alert_dialog_bg));
        alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Закрыть", (dialog, which) -> alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(DialogInterface::cancel));
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Поиск", (dialog, which) -> {
            reader();
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {requestPermissionWithRationale();}
}
```

Вызывается AlertDialog после нажатия на FloatingActionBtn.
Как добавить TextInput в AlertDialog? Программно (в java классе) или в xml...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же как и обычно. Создаете лейаут, в котором есть нужные виджеты, инфлейтите его во `View` и аттачите его в `AlertDialog`, приблизительно так:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setView(view);
```

Comment: а в MaterialAlertDialog его можно запихнуть? upd. получилось, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

          alert.setTitle("Title");
          alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
          final EditText input = new EditText(this);
          alert.setView(input);

          alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
              String value = input.getText();
 // Do something with value!
                }
             });

          alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     // Canceled.
                 }
         });

          alert.show();
```